# Notice: Undefined index: id c:\wamp\www\ompaps\blue\frontend\viewsong.php on line 3

Tags: php

Please someone should kindly help me on this...

```
<?php
require_once('../Administrator/PHP/connect.php');
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$getAlbumImage = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblalbum WHERE id = '$id'");
while($rowImage = mysql_fetch_array($getAlbumImage)){
$albumimage = $rowImage['albumimage'];
}
?>
```

Comment: You are using form to send request on this file?

Comment: No I didn't use form...just <div>

Answer (score 1):

Your html and php file should be like this:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="post.php" method="post">
   <p><input type="hidden" name="id" value="10" /></p>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**PHP:(post.php)**

```
<?php
    require_once('../Administrator/PHP/connect.php');

    if(isset($_REQUEST['id']) && ($_REQUEST['id'] != "")){
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
        $getAlbumImage = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblalbum WHERE id =".$id);
        while($rowImage = mysql_fetch_array($getAlbumImage)){
            $albumimage = $rowImage['albumimage'];
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks so much...it really help